# hide local listings from google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When using google maps api to display something google has started adding local restaurants/hotels into the map.
How can I hide them from appearing. I checked the same locations on sites that use maps (like yelp) and they successfully hide the local hotels/restaurants.
I've been looking for layers/overlays but can't figure out how I remove this default behavior.

[example](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=tongren%20lu&hl=en&ll=31.166985,121.35704&spn=0.472965,1.056747&sll=31.166985,121.35704&sspn=0.472965,1.056747&t=m&vpsrc=6&radius=37.5&z=17)
[image: These things]
These things are appearing on my maps. is it possible to hide these bubbles and names?

**edit**
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#36
says that 3.6 introduces business icons on by default. So setting v=3.5 as a parameter will hide the "Business icons".

**bounty**
Is there a way of hiding the business messages without sticking with an older version of the api?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

you can set them invisible by setting the map style properly. See

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html

and

http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

sth like that should do the trick (though not tested):

```
var noPoi = [
{
    featureType: "poi",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]   
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: noPoi});
```

Comment: Second link doesn't work, I can't get your code or the code at that link to work with the Google Maps Embed API 3, with iframe

Comment: This code only works when drawing the map from JS ex: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple, not when using iframes

Comment: You can use this wizard to generate the styles JSON you require: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/