# hide local listings from google maps api on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

This question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396722/hide-local-listings-from-google-maps-api) for JavaScript

But how to that on iOS with GMaps SDK 1.4 ???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep searching in the web ... 
I found that it's not possible for iOS GoogleMaps SDK to edit or hide the original listed places ...

But "[MapBox](http://www.mapbox.com)" is recommended for my situation ... I'll use it instead of GMaps