# Hide specific poi.business on gmap api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I succeeded to hide business POI on Google Maps API v3 with [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396722/hide-local-listings-from-google-maps-api).

But now I wonder if there is a way to be more specific.

I want to hide only hotels POI but still show restaurants and bars POI.

Is there a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to be more specific. You can refer to the [Styled Map Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType) to see what you can toggle.