# Remove Selected POIs from Google map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have generated an elaborate Google Map for an large local festival, I am involved with, which highlights venues throughout my local town where events will be taking place.  It has a hundred additional markers added.  Having most Points of Interest is good and highly relevant, but I would like to have a few removed from this particular map:

2 Are for car parks which will not be used as car parks for the weekend (There will be 2 or 3 additional large ones further out).

3 Are for very un-cooperative businesses who want the benefit of 50,000 extra people but don't want to contribute any money and are running their own things which are nothing to do the festival.

Here is a small segment of the map, how could I go about removing the "High Street Carpark" from this?  (This is perhaps the least important one to change but is the easiest to see).

[image: Small map]

It is marked aas similar to another question, but that has not been answered either.

Comment: The [list of features](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#style-features) helps you. There you can see which category you can remove. There is no way to remove one specific POI.

Comment: I don't want to remove a category.  I want to remove individual points.  I want to remove the two car parks which wont be car parks,

Comment: might you find it easier to find all the relevant points of interest, record lat/lng to db and add your own poi rather than rely upon google where you cannot, as far as i can see, be specific in the items from the collection you display?

Comment: *There is no way to remove one specific POI.* Is there anything unclear in what I stated in my comment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide specific poi.business on gmap api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455424/hide-specific-poi-business-on-gmap-api-v3)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Google Map styling system and do something like:

```
  var styles = {
    default: null,
    hide: [
      {
        featureType: 'poi.business',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'transit',
        elementType: 'labels.icon',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      }
    ]
  };
```

You must find here what to hide here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

The much easier way I could find is to use Google Map Styling Wizard:
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: This does not help.  I want to keep virtually all the pois.  I don't want to remove all businesses, I want almost all to remain.  I don't want to remove car parks they are useful, I want to remove this one.  How do I remove a particular one (it presumably has some unique reference id

Comment: I understand. You cant hide specific POI because they are all under categories like poi.attraction or poi.school. Either hide them all or show. I'm sorry I didn't help you but the question is interesting.