# Remover other places from Google Maps JS API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to remove all the places around my marker in Google Maps Javascript API. Is there any way to do it? I didn't find any useful information.

Here I show some places from Buenos Aires (screen shot from Google Maps, not from my JS implementation). All those brown markers must be gone.

[image: Maps Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking and to me it seems like you might want to check out this previously resolved post.

[hide local listings from google maps api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396722/hide-local-listings-from-google-maps-api)

This will help you remove the local listings from your google map.